# Date calculator : Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, date, selenium, scripting, selenium-webdriver

How can I verify if the calculated date is correct through selenium web driver?
Consider the following examples below:

**From Date:** 01/01/2001
**Duration:** 10
**To Date:** 01/10/2001

I will instruct selenium to input a date on from date field and duration.
The system shall automatically calculates the To date based on the inputted from date and duration.

I wonder if there's a way to verify if the calculated To Date is correct given that the inputted values on from date and duration fields may change time to time.

Static values for from date and duration fields is okay too - I guess.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using java.util methods. I assume you will be pass **From Date** and **Duration** as string to your selenium/webdriver from your test data set. You have to do following for each test data:

- Calculate the **To Date** using util method (Code below for getToDate).
- Get text in **To Date** using selenium/webdriver, for your test data.
- Compare the text fetched by selenium/webdriver with the text returned by your getToDate method.

The method to get **To Date**:

```
public static String getToDate(String fromDate, String duration){
    try {
        String[] arrFromDate = fromDate.split("/");
        int fromMonth = Integer.parseInt(arrFromDate[0])-1;
        int fromDay = Integer.parseInt(arrFromDate[1]);
        int fromYear = Integer.parseInt(arrFromDate[2]);
        int intDuration = Integer.parseInt(duration);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, fromDay);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, fromMonth);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, fromYear);   
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, intDuration);
        String toDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        return toDate;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Code to verify:

```
String appToDate = driver.findElement(By.id("toDate")).getText();
String myToDate = getToDate("01/01/2001","10");
boolean isToDateCorrect = false;
if (appToDate.equals(myToDate )){
    isToDateCorrect  = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest parsing the date instead of splitting the string

```
String strDate = "01/01/2001";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 10); // 10 == duration
String outStr = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```